# Binding a view to a controller property

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a controller that populates a list of items

```
/** controller/index.js **/
var IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({

      itemlist: function () {

           this.set('itemlist', ["a", "b", "c"]);
      };

});
```

and in my template I call it with

```
/** templates/index.hbs **/
{{#each item in itemlist}}

{{/each}}

{{view "list"}}
```

I want my sub-view to use the itemlist property from the controller.

```
/** views/list.js **/
var ListView = Ember.View.extend({

     perform: function () {


     }.observes('controller.itemlist')

});
```

It doesn't seem to be working. I'm using Ember App-Kit. I've tried referencing it as "index.itemlist" but to no avail. There are quite a few examples for using this same method for the index view but not for an injected view (I'm not sure if my terminology is correct for that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to pass that in using a binding:

```
{{view "list" itemlistBinding="itemlist"}}
```

Then you can access it in your `ListView` like this:

```
ListView = Ember.View.extend({
     perform: function () {
        console.log( this.get('itemlist');
     }.observes('itemlist')
});
```

Or you could pass in the controller:

```
{{view "list" itemlistBinding="controller"}}

ListView = Ember.View.extend({
     perform: function () {
        console.log( this.get('itemlist');
     }.observes('controller.itemlist')
});
```

Explanation (from comment below): By adding "Binding" to a variable name, you bind it's value to the variable in the quotation marks. That way if the variable in the quotation marks (itemlist of your controller) changes, so will itemlist in your ListView

Comment: What if I want to bind it to a different property? Will the view bind to the current working controller?

Comment: Thanks for that. Just a small clarification - what is "itemListBinding"? Is that just a variable or is it part of Ember? If its a variable, don't I need to reference it in the View?

Comment: By adding `Binding` to a variable name, you bind it's value to the variable in the quotation marks. That way if the variable in the quotation marks (`itemlist` of your controller) changes, so will `itemlist` in your `ListView`

Comment: Couldn't ask for a better explanation! Thanks very much!